# Value Old Does Not Work Out When The Form Refreshes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to add value `old()` so that when user fills out form and the form gets refreshes (if any error occured), the old value appears as value of input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Postal Code</label>
    <span class='text-danger'>*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_code" value="{{ old('post_code',$member->mbr_post_code??null) }}">
</div>
```

But now the problem is, it does not show the Old value of user however the form input is filled once.

So how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you saying that it isn't filling the field after you submitted the form now but it did work?

Comment: @Rwd Yes, I need also to determine if the user had added the Postal Code and it was stored at the DB, show it, and if not then show the Old value of user

Comment: you mean you are using this form to edit an existing entry? use old value if form validation redirects or use the object value instead?

Comment: as I know `old()` works only when laravel validation redirects back to the form, Is this happening to you?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin Yes this is for redirection after validation

Comment: @jefagem Please show us the controller method where validation used.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon No I want to show user Postal Code if it exists in the DB and if not, show the last user input that he enters on the form

Comment: Please update your question with the controller and validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use only {{ old('post_code') }} or you can update the code in this way `old('post_code',$member->mbr_post_code ? $member->mbr_post_code : '')` This is happening for `NULL`.

Comment: Please can you add an explanation for your answer.

Comment: I need also to determine if the user had added the Postal Code and it was stored at the DB, show it, and if not then show the Old value of user

Comment: @jefagem There is not any difference between `old('post_code',$member->mbr_post_code??null) ` and `old('post_code',$member->mbr_post_code ? $member->mbr_post_code : '') `

Comment: I agree with @AmitSenjaliya

Comment: Yes, there is little difference. When using NULL, it's not working, but if you are using an empty string instead of NULL, it's working.